# jQuery AJAX Internet Explorer/FF doesn't receive post/get information

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

I've tried to do a simple example with these files:

index.php:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button>click to alert data</button>

<div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

test.js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.post('echo.php',{tsest:"Clicked"},function(data){
            $('div').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

echo.php:

```
 <?php 
    echo $_POST['tsest'];
?>
```

In Chrome, I get the result `Clicked`, but in Internet Explorer I get this result: 
`Notice: Undefined index: tsest in C:\wamp\www\Examples\echo.php on line 2`

It seems like Internet Explorer can't receive POST/GET values from AJAX requests. I've just tried the same code on Firefox, and it seems not to work as well. Why is this happening? Is there anyway to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that, although I'm not very good with php. Both IE + FF **do** allow both `POST` and `GET` Ajax requests.

Comment: @Nunners I wish it was true. It seems like FF AND IE doesn't allow `POST` requests. I've just tried one more time the `GET` request method, and it works. Tried to use the `POST` request once again, and it failed :/

Comment: Please refer to the [jQuery Browser Support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) Page. If you are not using a supported browser this can occur, however if this was not supported in FF/IE it would be clearly identified in the jQuery Documentation of [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). There must be something wrong with either your echo.php page or something else in your code.